# Javascript reset ul list

Tags: javascript, html-lists, rebuild

I'm creating a ul list of Requests based on the results from an AJAX call. I want to search for specific Requests so that the list gets rebuilt with the search results but I can't get rid of the list once it's built. How can I do this?

```
onload = function () {
initRequestList(URL);

$("#statusSearch_btn").click(function () {
    document.getElementById("requestList").innerHTML = "";
    fillSearchParameters();
    initRequestList(status)
});
};

function fillSearchParameters() {
status = $("#status_txt").val();
};

function initRequestList(s) {
if (s !== null)
    URL = "http://localhost:58510/api/requests/" + status;
var requestList = document.getElementById("requestList");
jQuery.support.cors = true;
$.ajax({
    url: URL,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
        //console.log(data);
        $.each($(data), function (key, value) {
            var request = value;
            var requestListItem = document.createElement("li");
            requestListItem.className = "lijstBlok";
            var bold = document.createElement("b");
            var br = document.createElement("br");
            var br2 = document.createElement("br");
            var br3 = document.createElement("br");
            var requestStatus = document.createTextNode(request.status);
            var requestDd = document.createTextNode(request.departuredate);
            bold.appendChild(requestStatus);
            requestListItem.appendChild(bold);
            requestListItem.appendChild(br);
            requestListItem.appendChild(requestDd);
            requestListItem.appendChild(br3);
            var requestCity;
            for (i = 0; i < request.destinations.length; i++) {
                if (i !== (request.destinations.length - 1)) {
                    requestCity = document.createTextNode(request.destinations[i].city + ", ");
                    requestListItem.appendChild(requestCity);
                } else {
                    requestCity = document.createTextNode(request.destinations[i].city);
                    requestListItem.appendChild(requestCity);
                }
            }
            requestList.appendChild(requestListItem);
        });
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('Error in Operation');
    }
});
};
```

HTML

```
<body>
<div id="main">
    <div id="newRequestDiv">
        <button id="newRequestbtn" type="button">New Request</button>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div id="requestsDiv">
        <input type="text" id="status_txt" placeholder="Status" /><button id="status_btn" type="button">Search</button>
        <ul id="requestList">

        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="js/requestDashboard.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: "Get rid of the list once it's built"... do you mean `$('ul#requestList').html('');`? - that would clear the list.

Comment: I think    document.getElementById("requestList").innerHTML = "";    does the same thing. The list doesn't disappear.

Comment: It is - but the search button id in your markup , `status_btn` doesn't agree with your click event function `#statusSearch_btn`. Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem.